# Iterating over a list of DataFrame objects with a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame

`divisasIndica` is a list of `DataFrame` objects, and I have this code:

```
datachart=[]
def dchart ():
    for i in divisasIndica[:]:
        df=divisasIndica[i]
        data = [ dict(
            type = 'candlestick',
            open = df.Open,
            high = df.High,
            low = df.Low,
            close = df.Close,
            x = df.index,
            rsi=df.RSI,
            SMA50=df.SMA50,
            SMA200=df.SMA200,
            SAR=df.SAR,
            yaxis = 'y2',
            name = tit,
            increasing = dict( line = dict( color = INCREASING_COLOR ) ),
            decreasing = dict( line = dict( color = DECREASING_COLOR ) ),
        ) ]
        layout=dict()

        fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
        datachart.append(fig)
```

The question is can't I read a list of DataFrames with `for`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you expect to happen on this line: `df=i.divisasIndica[i]`?

Comment: When you do `for i in divisasIndica[:]`, `i` will be a `DataFrame` that you're interested in. You don't need `df=divisasIndica[i]`. Just do `for df in divisasIndica[:]:` and skip the part where you assign something to `df`.

Comment: I am updating my problem ... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of your list are already dataframes, no need to try to get them using an index. `for i in divisasIndica` gives you all the elements of `divisasIndica` directly, not their indexes. And there is no need to do `divisasIndica[:]`.

Change your code to this:

```
datachart=[]
def dchart ():
    for df in divisasIndica:
        data = [ dict(
            type = 'candlestick',
            open = df.Open,
            high = df.High,
            low = df.Low,
            close = df.Close,
            x = df.index,
            rsi=df.RSI,
            SMA50=df.SMA50,
            SMA200=df.SMA200,
            SAR=df.SAR,
            yaxis = 'y2',
            name = tit,
            increasing = dict( line = dict( color = INCREASING_COLOR ) ),
            decreasing = dict( line = dict( color = DECREASING_COLOR ) ),
        ) ]
        layout=dict()

        fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
        datachart.append(fig)
```

Comment: I have a list with 50 dataframes ... and I want to create another list with 50 dataframes, but adding in my new list of dataframes this dictionary

Comment: @PedroPuertas Please don't add more comments than necessary.. After doing `dchart(divisasIndica)` you need to print the list, not the function `print(datachart)`

Answer (score 0):

```
datachart=[]
def dchart (divisasIndica):
    for df in divisasIndica:
        data = [ dict(
            type = 'candlestick',
            open = df.Open,
            high = df.High,
            low = df.Low,
            close = df.Close,
            x = df.index,
            rsi=df.RSI,
            SMA50=df.SMA50,
            SMA200=df.SMA200,
            SAR=df.SAR,
            yaxis = 'y2',
            name = titu,
            increasing = dict( line = dict( color = INCREASING_COLOR ) ),
            decreasing = dict( line = dict( color = DECREASING_COLOR ) ),

        ) ]
        layout=dict()

        fig = dict( data=data, layout=layout )
        datachart.append(fig)
```